# How to inject spring bean into static classRule?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-test

How to inject spring bean into static classRule?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ConfigClass.class})
public class SimpleTest   {

 @ClassRule 
 public static SimpleClassRule simpleClassRule = new SimpleClassRule ();

}
```

Comment: Might be you'll have to extend `org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringClassRule` in the `SimpleClassRule`?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you extend **SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class** and override **withBeforeClasses, withBefores** methods:

```
public class CustomRunner extends SpringJUnit4ClassRunner {
    @Override
    protected Statement withBeforeClasses(Statement statement) {
        List<TestRule> testRules = classRules();
        // spring method to inject into existing object like injector.injectMembers(...);
        return super.withBeforeClasses(statement);
    }
}
```

important: this solution does not apply for RuleChains.

also I found out the following solution in **Spring JIRA**:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10252

> Currently it can be achieved by extending
>   DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener (DITEL) with additional logic
>   that looks for @Rule and @ClassRule fields and autowires them the same
>   way as test instance is autowired.